# Cmd+Tab not working

Tags: macos, application-switcher

We're having this problem with a Mac Pro running OSX 10.8.4 and 6 monitors with dual graphic cards+Triplehead. The <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> window does not show and it doesn't switch applications.

I temporarily solved this using [this guide](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4394899?start=0&tstart=0) by removing `com.apple.finder.plist` from `Library/Preferences`, but only for a minute before it reverted to not working again.

Any idea how to permanently solve this issue?

Comment: Who is rewriting your pref file ?

Comment: Try to log in as different user to see if something is changing your preferences.

Comment: You could also see if `killall Dock` fixes it or if there are any relevant log messages.

Answer (score 10):

The solution that worked for me was to open a Terminal window and type
 `sudo killall Dock` and hit the <kbd>⏎</kbd>(=enter) key and then entering my password and then the <kbd>⏎</kbd> key again. It will take around 6 - 8 seconds for the Dock to 'die' and then be restarted. If your password is not working then you are not an 'Administrator' on the computer in which case you will need to obtain that password from the Administrator.

Comment: Nice. This solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and removing .plist didn't fix anything.
After that I realized that de cmd+alt+esc shortcut didn't work either.
So I checked with the character viewer, and it appeared that my keyboard had 3 unfunctional keys (shift tab esc).
So...it might be worth checking that first...